# How to a function return return specific counts

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, for-loop, methods

Below is a function which counts for each character in a grid. 
I want to make this function return the counts for each character but I am stuck. Please, how can I improve the function below so that I can return each count which I require to process my other methods.

```
int getNeighborhood(const char** grid, int N, int row, int col, int& bCount, int& fCount, int& rCount, int& gCount){
   int currRow;
   int currCol;
   int countB = 0;
   int countF = 0;
   int countR = 0;
   int countG = 0;

   //loop through all 8 grids surrounding the current row and column.
   for(int i = -1; i < 2; i++)            
   {
      for(int j = -1; j < 2; j++){
         currRow = row + i;               //current row.
         currCol = col + i;               //current column.

         if(currRow >= 0 && currRow < N && currCol >= 0 && currCol < N){
            if(grid[row][col] == 'B')
            {
               ++countB;
            }
            if(grid[row][col] == 'F')
            {
               ++countF;
            }
            if(grid[row][col] == 'R')
            {
               ++countR;
            }
            if(grid[row][col] == 'G')
            {
               ++countG;
            }
         }
      }
   //return statement required
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use std::map

```
std::map<char,int> getNeighborhood(const char** grid, int N, int row, int col){
    int currRow;
    int currCol;
    //contain all character to count
    std::string chElementToCount = "BFGR"; 

    //The frequency is a map <char,int> correspond to <character to count, frequency>
    std::map<char, int> frequency; 

    // intialize all frequency by 0
    for (auto& ch: chElementToCount) {
        frequency.insert(std::make_pair(ch,0));
    }
    for(int i = -1; i < 2; i++)            
    {
        for(int j = -1; j < 2; j++){
            currRow = row + i;               //current row.
            currCol = col + i;               //current column.

            // just get value of current char for easier later access
            auto ch = grid[row][col];

            if(currRow >= 0 && currRow < N && currCol >= 0 && currCol < N){

                // the current char is a desired-to-count character then increase it frequency
                if (chElementToCount.find(ch) != std::string::npos)
                    frequency[ch]++;
            }
        }
    }
    return frequency;
}
```

This is an example for using std::map http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/

Comment: i do not have that much knowledge... i have to go as basic as posted.... can explain using arrays pls?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use `std::tuple`. first change the function signature to:

```
std::tuple<int,int,int,int> getNeighborhood(const char** grid, int N, int row, int col)
```

And use this return statement:

```
return std::make_tuple(countB,countF,countR,countG);
```

---

Since they are all the same type, you may also use `std::array`:

```
std::array<int,4> getNeighborhood(const char** grid, int N, int row, int col)
```

And use this return statement:

```
return std::array<int,4>{{countB,countF,countR,countG}};
```

Comment: i tried this but its not helping... a sample code would aid my understanding pls.

Comment: "i tried this but its not helping." what is not helping? I posted a code actually! you want a test case?

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is not clear, I'm assuming you want to get character count in bCount, fCount, rCount, gCount. There are two possible solutions

**Solution 1**
Use pointers to get the count, don't return anything

```
void getNeighborhood(const char** grid, int N, int row, int col, int *countB , int *countF , int *countR, int *countG ) {
int currRow;
int currCol;
*countB = 0;
*countF = 0;
*countR = 0;
*countG = 0;
for(int i = -1; i < 2; i++)            
{
   for(int j = -1; j < 2; j++){
     currRow = row + i;              
     currCol = col + i;               

     if(currRow >= 0 && currRow < N && currCol >= 0 && currCol < N){
        if(grid[row][col] == 'B')
        {
           ++*countB;
        }
        if(grid[row][col] == 'F')
        {
           ++*countF;
        }
        if(grid[row][col] == 'R')
        {
           ++*countR;
        }
        if(grid[row][col] == 'G')
        {
           ++*countG;
        }
     }
  }

}
```

Now call the function passing it pointers for each character count

**Solution 2**
Create an array that would hold the count of each character and make your function return an array.

Comment: to call the function would be ---                                        getNeighborhood(const char** grid, int N, int row, int col, int *countB , int *countF , int *countR, int *countG );      ?

Comment: Assuming that you have created char count variables 
int countB , countF , countR, countG;
Call the function like this 
 getNeighborhood(const char** grid, int N, int row, int col, &countB , &countF , &countR, &countG )
When function return you should have desired values in the respective variables.

Comment: i am working on the other methods would get back to you as soon as i run the complete program..... but i sure do understand your explanation

Answer (score 0):

What would your function return if called with invalid arguments, such as, e.g. `row  > N-2`? This example shows, that your function can fail and should have a way to say it.

In cases, where your function both has to report success/failure and some result values, the success/failure information is usually reported with the functions return value. The result values are reported via `OUT` arguments.

This leads to the following code, where I used a struct to aggregate the result values.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
//#include <vector>

struct CountResult
{
    size_t B;
    size_t F;
    size_t R;
    size_t G;
    CountResult()
        : B(0)
        , F(0)
        , R(0)
        , G(0)
    {}
    void Reset()
    {
        B = 0; F = 0; R = 0; G = 0;
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stm, const CountResult& x)
{
    stm << "{ B = " << x.B << ", F = " << x.F << ", R = " << x.R << ", G = " << x.G << "}";
    return stm;
}

bool GetNeighborhood(const char * const * const grid, size_t N, size_t row, size_t col, CountResult & result)
{
    if (nullptr == grid)
        return false;
    // Range check. Operation only allowed for squares with a full border.
    if (row > (N - 2) || row < 1 || col > (N - 2) || col < 1)
        return false;

    result.Reset();

    for(int16_t r = -1; r < 2; r++)
        for (int16_t c = -1; c < 2; c++)
        {
            if (!(r == 0 && c == 0))
            {
                switch (grid[row + r][col + c])
                {
                case 'B': result.B++; break;
                case 'F': result.F++; break;
                case 'R': result.R++; break;
                case 'G': result.G++; break;
                default: // illegal value in grid!
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    const size_t N = 11;
    char **grid = new char *[N]; // TODO: check for nullptr (out of memory)
    for (size_t r = 0; r < N; r++)
    {
        grid[r] = new char[N]; // TODO: check for nullptr (out of memory)
        for (size_t c = 0; c < N; c++)
            grid[r][c] = 'G';
    }

    CountResult result;
    if (GetNeighborhood(grid, N, 5, 5, result))
    {
        std::cout << "Result = " << result << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "GetNeighborhood() returned false." << std::endl;
    }

    // TODO: delete[] the rows and the grid itself.

    return 0;
}
```

As this code is running in main, I did not bother to write the cleanup code for the heap allocated grid. Usually, it should be done.

Speaking of usually, usually you would use `std::vector< std::vector<char> >` or alike to avoid all the low level memory leak check code I hinted with my `TODO:` statements.